# Почему подсчёт числа фибоначчи занимает O(2^n) времени?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, рекурсия, числа-фибоначчи

```js
function getFib(n) {
    if (n <= 2) {
    return n;
  }
  
  return getFib(n - 1) + getFib(n - 2);
}
```

Comment: Потому что вы его так написали

Comment: Извините, если неправильно задал вопрос. Не понимаю как работает рекурсия в данном случае. Как из Т (n) = Т (n-1) + Т (n-2) может следовать O(2^n)?

Comment: Ну вообще говоря, сложность алгоритма будет O(F(N)), где F(N) - N-ное число Фибоначчи. А для них известно, что F(N) ~= 1.618 ^ N, а это в свою очередь можно оценить как O(2 ^ N). Либо можно сказать, что T(N) - возрастающая функция, поэтому T(N) = T(N - 1) + T(N - 2) <= 2 * T(N - 1), а из этого уже напрямую следует асимптотика O(2 ^ N)

Comment: Вот смотрите сколько надо сделать вызовов для n = 5: https://pastebin.com/TaexzcB5  Для 6 понадобиться выполнить это все фактически дважды. Да, это не совсем квадрат, но очень близко к нему. Проблема алгоритма в том, что ему надо считать функцию для одного и того же аргумента много раз

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/mXVjmZY/01.jpg :)

Comment: @Harry, выглядит как линейный :)

Comment: @Grundy В логарифмических координатах. Получается — формула приведена — O(1.618..^N)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Выпишем сложность `T(n)` для вашей функции: `T(0) = 1`, `T(1) = 1`, `T(2) = 1`, `T(n) = 1 + T(n - 1) + T(n - 2)`.

Распечатаем таблицу для чисел Фибоначчи и `T`:

> ```
>  n F(n) T(n)
>  3    2    3
>  4    3    5
>  5    5    9
>  6    8   15
>  7   13   25
>  8   21   41
>  9   34   67
> 10   55  109
> ```

Угадываем формулу: `T(n) = 2F(n) - 1, n >= 3`.

Доказываем формулу по индукции. База для `n = 3, n = 4` проверяется непосредственно. Индукционный переход: пусть формула верна для значений меньших `n`, тогда

```
 T(n) = 1 + T(n - 1) + T(n - 2) =      # реккурентная формула для T
 = 1 + 2F(n - 1) - 1 + 2F(n - 2) - 1 = # индукционное предположение
 = 2(F(n - 1) + F(n - 2)) - 1 =        # алгебра
 = 2F(n) - 1                           # реккурентная формула для чисел Фибоначчи
```

Получили `T(n) = 2F(n) - 1`. Индукционный переход доказан. Формула в целом доказана.

Формула Бине: `F(n) = O((1 + sqrt(5)) / 2)^n)`. Следовательно и `T(n) = O((1 + sqrt(5)) / 2)^n)`.

Вывод: `T(n)` растёт как экспонента с основанием `1.618...`.

**P.S.** Вы написали функцию с ошибкой. Число `getFib(2)` должно быть равно `1`. А у вас `2`.